# Ubuntu install on MSI GS60 6QE

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, msi

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Win10 on my MSI and do understand that they're fairly notorious for making linux installs a hassle. I've made pretty minimal progress with the install and get stuck and the load screen whenever I try to install from an ISO on a usb. Ive turned off secure boot, fast boot, and Intel speed technology in the BIOS. I can only boot to the USB when its in Legacy mode, but I feel like it needs to be in UEFI mode for it to boot properly to Ubuntu. I used RUFUS for the USB installer which is compatible with UEFI. Am I no longer looking at BIOS issues and should be looking elsewhere? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: Ive now got a working Ubuntu partition on the HDD however now when I boot the computer back up I can't access grub no matter the priority I set in the BIOS. It just goes straight to windows...

**EDIT 2**: Ive successfully got my computer to boot to grub every time giving me the option of windows or ubuntu, now there are issues with ubuntu allowing me to log on and use the os. Ive done editing with nomodeset after hitting E with Ubuntu highlighted, but that change doesn't save and if I dont do it every time I cant boot to ubuntu...

**EDIT 3**: Now I run into a new boot issue. I had it working for a while, got some drivers and Gnome set up, then when I went to restart to check it was solid and sturdy on boot, it hung at the boot screen. Typical purple/black hang error usually solved by nomodeset or nvidia/nouveau.modeset=0, however these solutions didn't work for me. I either experienced the same hang or was left with a text-based boot screen that yet again got stuck

**EDIT 4**: Last update before I let this question sit. I reinstalled Ubuntu, had to do nomodeset in the try ubuntu option and then install it back into the reformatted partition. Got into the os, it was scaled pretty large so I downloaded the nvidia driver. Restarted to apply changed and wasnt able to boot so went back and did nomodeset again. Got access into OS but the nvidia driver was gone. Redownloaded it with some other drivers and Gnome. Went to log out to change to gnome and every time Id log in the Id get a notification saying Ubunutu has encountered an error followed by a short pause and then I would get kicked from my account and put back to the log in screen. I'm now right back to where I was. Ive narrowed it down to graphic drivers and possibly gnome? I will wait to see if there are other options.

**GRAPHICS CARD: Nvidia Geforce 970M
CPU: Intel i7 6700 HQ**

Comment: Ubuntu should boot fine in Legacy mode. Does it load far enough to see any messages on the screen? If so, are there any errors?

Comment: I have seen at least two different boot parameters suggested for MSI systems.  [SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544 and:MSI PX60 2qd 034us Haswell & Optimus libata.force=noncq for SSD hangup
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296878

Comment: In the future, if you want to edit your own posts, please log in first so your changes don't have to go through review as an “edit suggestion”.